# Accessing child component inside modal using ViewChild in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild

I have a PrimeNG table as a child component and it has the following code:

`child-component.html`

```
<p-table 
    [value]="data" 
    [autoLayout]="true"
    [loading]="loading"
    [(selection)]="selectedItems" #dt
>
```

`child-component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: "manager-grid",
    templateUrl: "./grid.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./grid.component.scss"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

    public _data: Array<any>;
    public _settings: any;
    public _loading: boolean;
    public total = 100;
    public selectedItems: any[];
    public _columnFilters: any;
    @ViewChild('dt') table: Table;
```

Now I am including this component in parent components as follows:

```
<manager-grid  [data]="data" [settings]="tableSettings" [loading]="isLoading"></manager-grid>
```

The child component is added in a modal and so when I try to access the `selectedItems` variable, it is returning `undefined`. I am using following code for this :

```
@ViewChild(GridComponent) gridComponent: GridComponent;

const items = this.gridComponent.selectedItems;
```

I am using NG Bootstrap modal and I think the issue is that, when the page is initialized, the child component is not part of the DOM as it is in modal. How can I access the element inside the modal ? Any workaround ?

Comment: when you try to access items data? are you sure that at the moment when you try to read it, the component fully mounted and initialized?

I'm asking about this line:
`const items = this.gridComponent.selectedItems;`

Comment: @AntonKononenko Yes. Actually there is a button in the modal and I am trying to access the selected items on button click.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086401/accessing-child-component-inside-modal-using-viewchild-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment113325835_64086401

Comment: is this button being clicked before or after `selection` from PrimeNG table is triggered?

Comment: Yes. It is clicked after the selection has been made. Actually I have included this child component two times. One is in the modal and the other one is not in modal. For the table, which is not in modal, I am getting the selected items. But in the modal I am not getting even if I use `ViewChildren`

Comment: can you do a stackblitz based on your code for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method for opening the modal, access `selectedItems` after the modal is opened. You may try the following -

```
openModal() {
  // open modal code goes here
  if (this.gridComponent) {
    items = this.gridComponent.selectedItems;
  }
}
```

If it does not work, you may try settimeout -

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (this.gridComponent) {
    items = this.gridComponent.selectedItems;
  }
},0);
```

Comment: This is also not working. In the modal open function, there will not be any items as it is only possible to select the items once the modal is opened. The timeout option is also showing undefined.

Comment: How about you check whether the gridComponent is undefined or not ?

Comment: It is. That is the issue here. When I try to access the child component from the parent inside a modal using ViewChild, it is not getting the reference. If I use it without modal, everything is working fine.

Comment: you need to provide stackblitz, assumption is not working here. Need to see your code